# Intercepting winsock recvfrom function gives invalid address error

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, winsock2

I'm trying to intercept winsock2 calls to troubleshoot a case where UDP packets between processes on the same host intermittently vanish. When they "vanish" they vanish for something like 20 seconds, which is enough to abort the process being run.

I managed to get the DLL injection to work, and 2 winsock calls are intercepted correctly (I hope) because I can do a simple print, but I need to be able to process the address information so I can track who sends what to whom...

Unfortunately, the upstream process I'm injecting into is apparently calling recvfrom (Yes, not the WSA... equivalent, this is old ported POSIX code) with NULL's for the "from" and "fromlen" parameters. If I don't fiddle with them at all the receive works. If I do the below, I get "Invalid Address" errors (Winsock error 10014).

An I doing something stupid here? Not that I would be surprised.... And yes, it would be easier to rebuild the target application with the desired debugging, but the build environment is down due to a data center migration, and I need ammunition to say "it's not the application."

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mhook.h"
#include <winsock2.h>

// typedefs for function pointers...

typedef int(WINAPI *rcvfrom_ptr) (
SOCKET          s,
char            *buf,
int             len,
int             flags,
struct sockaddr *from,
int             *fromlen
);

typedef int(WINAPI *sendto_ptr) (
_In_       SOCKET                s,
_In_ const char                  *buf,
_In_       int                   len,
_In_       int                   flags,
_In_       const struct sockaddr *to,
_In_       int                   tolen
);

// Function pointers for original calls.

rcvfrom_ptr orig_rcvfrom;
sendto_ptr orig_sendto;

//
// Helper functions.
//

typedef union sockaddrs {
    struct sockaddr from;
    struct sockaddr_in in_from;
    // Need to verify Ipv6 support. may need to remigrate back to VS 2015
    //struct sockaddr_in6 in6_from;
} tsockaddrs;

char *printaddr(char *buff,const int buffsz, const tsockaddrs *addr)
{
    ...
}

// Shim functions.
//
// Still working on getting them to actually work and do what I need. 
// But I may as well develop the skeleton

int WINAPI Myrecvfrom(SOCKET          s,
                char            *buf,
                int             len,
                int             flags,
                struct sockaddr *from,
                int             *fromlen
)
{
    int result;
    struct sockaddr *all_froms;
    char addrbuff[100] = "";
    int newfromlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    all_froms = (struct sockaddr *)malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    memset((void *)all_froms,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    printf("Receiving Packet!\n");
    if (from == NULL) {
        printf("\tFrom addr == null, using internal structures\n");
        result =  (orig_rcvfrom)(s, buf, len, flags, all_froms, &newfromlen);
    } else {
        printf("\tFrom addr != null, using passed structures\n");
        result =  (orig_rcvfrom)(s, buf, len, flags, from, fromlen);
        memcpy_s((void*)&all_froms,sizeof(all_froms),(void *)from,*fromlen);
        if (fromlen != NULL) {
            newfromlen=*fromlen;
        } else { 
            newfromlen=sizeof(struct sockaddr);
        }
    }

    if (result >0) {printf("received %d bytes\n",result);}
    else if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {printf("Socket Error %d occurred!\n",WSAGetLastError());}
    if (newfromlen >0) {
        if (printaddr(addrbuff,sizeof(addrbuff),(tsockaddrs *)all_froms)!=NULL) {
            printf("received %d bytes from on port %d from host %s\n",result,((tsockaddrs *)(all_froms))->in_from.sin_port,addrbuff);
        }
        if (from != NULL) {
            memcpy_s((void*)from,sizeof(struct sockaddr),(void*)&all_froms,newfromlen);
        }
        else
        {

        }
        if (fromlen != NULL) *fromlen=newfromlen;
    }
    else {
            printf("received %d bytes from unknown port and host\n",result);
    }

    if (all_froms != NULL) {free(all_froms);}
    return result;
}

int WINAPI Mysendto(SOCKET                s,
    const char                  *buf,
    int                   len,
    int                   flags,
    const struct sockaddr *to,
    int                   tolen
)
{
    printf("Sending packet!\n");

    return orig_sendto(s, buf, len, flags, to, tolen);
}

BOOL AttachHooks(void)
{
    BOOL sethooks;
    orig_rcvfrom = (rcvfrom_ptr)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ws2_32"), "recvfrom");
    sethooks = Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&orig_rcvfrom, Myrecvfrom);
    if (sethooks) {
        orig_sendto = (sendto_ptr)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ws2_32"), "sendto");
        sethooks &= Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&orig_sendto, Mysendto);
    }
    return sethooks;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        printf_s("This is an attached DLL!\n");
        AttachHooks();
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: The *UDP* packets vanish: that means that they are being sent by source, but they never arrive to destination. This is OK from *UDP*'s *PoV*. If you're tweaking `recvfrom` (note: this function is perfectly fine, I have a feeling that `WSARecvFrom` is just a wrapper over it) you are doing it on the destination side as well, and if the packet didn't reach it there's a low chance you could find out smth new. Also: how do you call `Myrecvfrom`? what arguments (still 0 for `from` and `fromLen`)?

Comment: The full description for error **10014** is "**The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call.**" This seems more related to a memory violation due to process memory mapping problems with injected code than winsock code.

Comment: @christifati -- I'm injecting this DLL and overriding the winsock2 recvfrom. And my objective is to eventually show that the packet sent by process1 never makes it to process 2, (or vice versa).

Comment: @Frankie_C in theory, wouldn't the heap be the same in the injected DLL? If not, any ideas on how to get the address data? I guess I could do completely parallel read on the socket using MSG_PEEK...

Comment: I am aware of the *dll* injection purpose, But that was kind of my point. If you send some msg from source, but `recvfrom` doesn't capture it on destination (meaning that it was discarded somewhere in between), all the code that you run on destination (e.g. `Myrecvfrom`) is  useless, since it won't be executed. Now, how does the original code call `recvfrom`? Do you have a snippet? Also any chance that the sender is an *IPv6*?

Comment: And I just thought of something... What if my allocation of the from? buffer died... Nope. Pass a pointer to get the address, it dies with that error. If I pass NULLS, and peek the buffer, I get the contents. I guess I'll have to go with that. Luckily these are SunRPC formatted packets with RPC ID's and program/call numbers. So, I'll be able to get the data out that way if nothing else. Not exactly the way I WANT to do it, since I wanted the addresses too, but if that's how i HAVE to do it. So be it.

Comment: @christifati -- I can't really speak to how it's called without delving deep into a 3rd party library. I plan on putting similar debugging code in send/sendto and recv/rcvfrom so I can say "here is the datagram that was sent at 3 second intervals w/o response, and we see in this other debug output that it did/didn't make it to the target process and the response did/didn't get sent and was/wasn't received..." Since the missing packets are the start of the UDP "handshake" between the processes, I can filter based on the RPC info. I was just hoping to be able to filter on the address to.

Comment: This is where I was aiming. Check [\[MSDN\]: recvfrom function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120(v=vs.85).aspx): the reason why it yields `WSAEFAULT`: "*The buffer pointed to by the buf or from parameters are not in the user address space, or the fromlen parameter is too small to accommodate the source address of the peer address.*"

Comment: Well, since my allocated buf worked for my peek, I can try sending a random 1KB buffer with that as the "addrlen" parameter and see what happens. It's SUPPOSED TO be a struct sockaddr *, but if it wants more space, I can certainly give it to it.

Comment: OK, now I really am learning to hate WINSOCK.... The pointer is SUPPOSED TO BE to a struct sockaddr (size 16 bytes), It turns out to be a pointer to a 28 byte struct instead... Now I get to go spelunking in the header file to see what this alternate struct is supposed to be, or if I am somehow loading the wrong header file.

Comment: Shit! I don't know how to take this to chat without spamming the question with too many comments (when move to chat option automatically appears). I think I now know what you're on now, I thought that you control the source code of the 2 apps, but apparently you don't. Note that the 28 bytes might be the  *IPv6* that I was talking about. `sockaddr`, and `sockaddr_in` structs both have 16 bytes. So far, *VStudio2010` doesn't seem to like `sockaddr_in6` :) (most likely, I have to (un)define smth to make things right).

Comment: I do and dont' control the source code of the 2 applications. I can't currently build the 2 apps because the build environment is currently dead in the water with no ETA for coming online. So, I have to hack it this way instead. I have the address info now that I'm aware of the differences in length from the size defined in the header file. (Thanks a LOT MS!) And from here I can dig through until I get the ports and IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the issue is that the ACTUAL size of the reply was more than the size of "struct sockaddr." It in fact was a SOCKADDR_IN6 structure coming back. Used an arbitrary buffer of 200 bytes instead of the 28-byte sockaddr structure and I was able to pull in the data.

In the process, I wound up converting to "peeking" the received data instead of processing it after it was pulled in. When the PC with the source code finishes installing updates, I'll post it.

Working from home is fairly isolating, and there isn't anyone who lives in winsock in my office anyway. It was really helpful to "chat" in the comments.